# linux or windows shell script to upload a file and copy it to another server

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I am struggling with a problem. I have:

- ServerA (is closer to me and much faster)
- ServerB (is my website where I want the final file to stay)
  so what I want to do with the shell script (either Windows batch or linux, I have cygwin installed) is, passing the filename as parameter:

1) upload with FTP a file to ServerA

2) login with ssh on serverB and wget the file from serverA

I managed to do 1 with a shell script, but I don't understand how to do step2 in the shell?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use `scp` to directly copy from `serverA` to `serverB` in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `scp` to accomplish step 2. You can use the syntax:

`scp path/to/file serverb@hostname:/path/to/destination`.

You can read more about the syntax for `scp` here: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use TeraTerm which has a powerful scripting language to automate both tasks.